# IUnknown_SetSite reference counter behavior

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

As I am currently in need to use Windows API's `IUnknown_SetSite()` from within a C# application, I am trying to understand this function's internals. I have found [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773817(v=vs.85).aspx) which in turn forwarded me to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683869(v=vs.85).aspx) which states the following:

> The object should hold onto this pointer, calling IUnknown::AddRef in
>   doing so. If the object already has a site, it should call that
>   existing site's IUnknown::Release, save the new site pointer, and call
>   the new site's IUnknown::AddRef.

Now, please consider the following code (assuming that I have correctly declared Windows API's prototypes, interfaces, GUIDs and so on elsewhere, as well as the variables I am using):

```
/* Create COM Object of ComClass_1 and get reference to its IUnknown */
CoCreateInstance(ref ComClass_1_id,
                 IntPtr.Zero,
                 (CLSCTX.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER),
                 ref IID_IUNKNOWN,
                 out intptr_ComClass_1_IUnknown);

/* This actually is not necessary to understand the question itself, but
   keeps additional complexity from us (without the following line, the
   ComClass_1 object would destroy itself if the reference counter for its
   IUnknown interface would reach zero, and for this question, I would like
   to keep this aspect from being discussed) */
CoCreateInstance(ref ComClass_1_id,
                 IntPtr.Zero,
                 (CLSCTX.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER),
                 ref IID_I_SOME_OTHER_INTERFACE,
                 out intptr_ComClass_1_ISomeOtherInterface);

/* Create COM Object of ComClass_2 and get reference to its IUnknown */
CoCreateInstance(ref ComClass_2_id,
                 IntPtr.Zero,
                 (CLSCTX.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER),
                 ref IID_IUNKNOWN,
                 out intptr_ComClass_2_IUnknown);

/* Now set ComClass_1 object's site to ComClass_2 object */
IUnknown_SetSite(intptr_ComClass_1_IUnknown, intptr_ComClass_2_IUnknown);
```

My question is actually simple:

After the first line, the `ComClass_1` object's site obviously is the `ComClass_1` object itself. Thus, if I take the reference literally, that object will call `Release()` on its own `IUnknown` interface during execution of the last line. Consequently, I must not release that interface later.

This does not make sense IMHO, and according to some tests I did, it is not true (if my test methods were correct, `ComClass_1` object's `IUnknown` reference counter did *not* decrease during the execution of the last line).

But since correctly releasing or not releasing COM interfaces is crucial, I would like to know for sure what is going on there. The question boils down to what the documentation does mean when it says "... has a site ...".

Personally, I think that it must be "... has another site than the object itself is ...", but I strongly would like to know what the COM / interop experts out there think about it.

Comment: That advice is directed at somebody that *implements* IObjectSite::SetSite().  You are only using it so nothing in that comment applies to you.

Comment: Yes, but I am using COM objects / classes which are made by Microsoft (i.e. which are part of Windows) or some other well-known manufacturer, so I am quite sure that their behavior adheres to that specification. And additionally, I think *every* implementor of `IObjectSite` *must* adhere to that specification because otherwise the *users* of that interface would never know if or if not they explicitly should call `Release()` after having used `SetSite()`.

Comment: How you *know* that the reference count doesn't change is not obvious at all.  You can't see it when you use raw IntPtr variables.  And the return value of AddRef/Release is only advisory, code may decide to control the lifetime of the object by itself and will then ignore reference counts, typically always returning 1.

Comment: You are right in general, but: In this case, I have used `Marshal.Release()` to test the behavior, and the COM objects I am using happen to behave as expected (at least seemingly). The code above is a reduced version to make my problem clear. During the tests, I first have referenced the `IUnknown` interface of every COM object multiple times, then have called `Marshal.Release()` multiple times on the pointers I had got. The return value of `Marshal.Release()` decreased by one upon every call, so I strongly assume my tests are meaningful at least for the objects I am interested in.

Comment: And if those tests indeed would be not meaningful, that would make my question even more important ...

Comment: *"After the first line, the `ComClass_1` object's site obviously is the `ComClass_1` object itself"* -- How so?  Why is its site not `NULL`?  Or, on the other hand, the object should call `AddRef` on itself, something that is done automatically when using smart pointers.  As for your second `CoCreateInstance`, you can only observe the behavior described in the comments if the object is a singleton; you could just call `AddRef` on the first object so the sample would work with any object.

Comment: @acelent Actually, your first sentences could be considered my question. Could an object's site be `NULL` at all? My tests did only relate to the first and the last line. The second line has the only intention to prevent distracting discussions about the self-destruction of the object which *possibly* could happen *if* its reference counters all became 0 when the last line would be executed. Therefore, I intentionally have chosen an interface other than IUnknown in the second line, i.e. the object won't destroy itself due to weird things which happen to its `IUnknown` interface.

Comment: All interfaces inherit from IUnknown, there is no way to isolate yourself from it to avoid "weird things".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Your assumption is incorrect, the object is not created with itself as the site. Just call SetSite and let the object deal with the lifetime issues related to a existing old site it **might** have. You are only responsible for objects **you** create/AddRef/QueryInterface.

---

A object generally never uses itself as a site. A objects site usually starts out as NULL. A site is used to connect two objects together, the connection is one way and lets the object interact with its host/owner. You are usually implementing the site **or** the object that needs a site yourself.

IUnknown_SetSite is just a helper function, all it does is:

```
hr = ptr->QueryInterface(IObjectWithSite, &i1);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = i1->SetSite(unkSite);
  i1->Release();
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) return hr;
}
hr = ptr->QueryInterface(ISomeOtherInterfaceThatHasASetSiteMethod, &i2);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) ...
...
```

everything it does is normal COM lifetime management and it tries a couple of interfaces, not just IObjectWithSite.

If the object implements one of the interfaces that has a SetSite method, its implementation of it should look something like this:

```
IUnknown *pOld = this->m_pSite;
if (pUnkSite) pUnkSite->AddRef();
this->m_pSite = pUnkSite;
if (pOld) pOld->Release();
```

...and if non-null, `this->m_pSite` is released when the object is destroyed. `this->m_pSite` starts out as NULL because the object is not connected to a site. If the object is thread safe it would use `InterlockedExchangePointer` when assigning the new pointer to `this->m_pSite`. `IUnknown_Set` can do all of this for simple implementations of SetSite. MSDN does say that the implementation should Release first and then AddRef but the order does not matter if everyone follows the COM rules. The caller already has a reference to the site they pass in so it cannot be destroyed by the Release even if the old site and the new site is the same object instance.

The answer is actually quite simple. You don't have to worry about anything, the SetSite implementation will AddRef the new site and release it when it no longer needs a site. It is safe to pass NULL and any interface pointer as the new site **except** the object itself (`foo->SetSite(foo);`) because then the object would never be released. Calling SetSite with the same pointer multiple times is also safe.

Comment: Thank you very much for that excellent and exceptionally clear answer. As I wrote in my question, I already didn't believe my initial assumption and my own tests proved it to be wrong. But knowing that something is wrong does not mean knowing what is right, and you have clarified that.